# Configuring Tesseract OCR to read words of same font size

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using **Tesseract 3.05.01** for **Windows** to extract text from an image containing few lines.
The lines are surrounded by a rounded rectangle.
[[Image attached for reference]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1emxr.png).

Tesseract detects the rounded rectangle as "C" at the beginning and ">" at the end of the line.

*This is what Tesseract returns:*

```
The Richter scale is used for measuring the
magnitude of which natural phenomenon?

C Earthquake >
C Hurricane >
C Tsunami
```

---

I tried including ">" in **blacklist**, but the blacklisted symbol **gets replaced by something similar**.
So I think if there is an option to *extract only characters of similar size*, then it would ***avoid the shapes***.

**Is there any way to detect only lines of similar font size/height?** or
**Suggest me any method to overcome this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a whitelist instead of a blacklist that includes all letters you want to have!
In tesseract.js for example this ist:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist: "abcdefghijklmnop ...."
```